# Is it possible to run program in onedrive?

Tags: zip, unzip, onedrive

I have requirement to unzip a file automatically whenever it is pasted in specified folder in onedrive (ex: zipfolder). So i basically want to know that, is it possible to **run any program in onedrive** that can fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If you were really dedicated to the task, what you could do is set up a web service with a webhook attached to the folder that you are wanting to do this in. When the webhook fires, your service can connect to OneDrive, download the file, unzip, and re-upload the contents.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible to run a program from onedrive...One drive is a cloud based server or rather storage,You may be forced to download it and install it from your hard disk